# Create anchoring with Xslt from xml document

Tags: xml, xslt, anchor

I am trying to create html from xml document with Xslt 1.0. In the xml document, there are customers and in the name attribute of some customers there is "see XXXX"  information.

Here is the xml document;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customers>
    <customer name="Adam Dev" category="A1" phone="1234543" />
    <customer name="Jerry Sngiler (see Matt Pcneiv)" category="" phone="" />
    <customer name="Heid Schwan" category="B1" phone="121257456" />
    <customer name="Matt Pcneiv" category="A2" phone="65656565" />
    <customer name="John Lombak" category="A2" phone="787878787" />
    <customer name="April Ozil (see Heid Schwan)" category="" phone="" />
    <customer name="Terry Hill" category="B1" phone="1212121212" />    
</customers>
```

I want to create anchoring for the "name" attribute to the related xml node in the xml document like below.I mean when a user clicks the Matt Pcneiv on the second node, page jumps to the Matt Pcneiv on the 4.node.Again when a user clicks Heid Schwan on the 6.node , page jumps to the Heid Schwan on 3.node.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
th,td
{
padding:5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:600px">
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Category</th>     
  <th>Phone</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Adam Dev</td>
  <td>A1</td>       
  <td>1234543</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  **<td>Jerry Sngiler (see <a href="#C1">Matt Pcneiv</a>)</td>**
  <td></td>     
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  **<td><a id="C2">Heid Schwan</a></td>**
  <td>B1</td>       
  <td>121257456</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  **<td><a id="C1">Matt Pcneiv</a></td>**
  <td>A2</td>       
  <td>65656565</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John Lombak</td>
  <td>A2</td>       
  <td>787878787</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  **<td>April Ozil (see <a href="#C2">Heid Schwan</a>)</td>**
  <td></td>     
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Terry Hill</td>
  <td>B1</td>       
  <td>1212121212</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I do this with xsl?I would appreciate if you could help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer to fill out the category and phone and delete the reference?

Comment: I would but it is not a decision that I can take, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, then. First thing: whoever designed your input XML is an idiot. For one thing, you have a structured data tool at your disposal; why would you cram two names into one slot? For another, as sure as hell there will be two customers with the same name one day.

With that out of the way, what you need to do here is extract the referenced name and use it as a key to link to the referenced person's anchor:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="customer-by-name" match="customer" use="@name" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Category</th>     
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="customers/customer"/>  
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="customer">
    <tr>
      <td><a id="{generate-id()}"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></a></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@category"/></td>       
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@phone"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="customer[contains(@name, ' (see ')]">
    <xsl:variable name="ref-name" select="substring-before(substring-after(@name, ' (see '), ')')" />
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@name, ' (see ')"/>
            <xsl:text> (see </xsl:text>
            <a href="#{generate-id(key('customer-by-name', $ref-name))}"><xsl:value-of select="$ref-name"/></a>
            <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
      </td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@category"/></td>       
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@phone"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you michael for your solution.

Do you think it is possible to add grouping over Category node to your solution?How can I apply Muenchian Method to your solution?

Comment: You shouldn't have any problems combining the two.